# "Twig-with-leaf"-like insect in central Mexico

Tags: species-identification, entomology

**What's that?!** I have googled around and found insects that looks like a twig, and others that look like a leaf, but this one looks deceptively like a leaf at the end of a twig (I swear it's a real living thing despite the appearances: it has legs and moves around!). As you can see from my hand on the photo it is also fairly big (well, at least for my European standards...).

- **Location:** Morelia, Mexico (about 2000m high, in the tropics)
- **Time:** October (humid season), in the morning

[image: top view with scale]

[image: side view]

Comment: And about your European standards: the European praying mantis is up to 9 cm and occurs all over Southern Europe and even at isolated locations in Germany. [See](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_mantis) Though I admit I was startled too when I encountered one. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a Mexican/Texas unicorn [mantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis), which is of the species *[Phyllovates chlorophaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllovates_chlorophaena)*.

[image]

[image]